# Python & OpenCV: improving code for object detection and finding center of it

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I'm trying to write a code to find contours and extract the bounding rectangle coordinates, then find center coordinate and draw center point. But I don't like the result of code execution.

Here's a code in Python:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
 
image = cv2.imread('res.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_image, (7,7) ,10)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 160, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
 
for c in cnts: 
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
 
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 4, (255, 255, 255), -1)
 
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is what I get now:

[image]

This is what I expect to get:

[image]

Why I get such result? How can I improve this code?

Comment: can you post original image (res.png)?

Comment: Yes, here it is: https://i.ibb.co/9rsr3RY/res-orig.png

Comment: you need to know that "object" must be white, and background must be black. then the moments calculation actually uses the object pixels, not the background pixels.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz how to make it through code?

Comment: pass `THRESH_BINARY_INV` to `threshold` instead

Comment: @Silentcow were you able to invert the image and solve?

Comment: @JeruLuke yes, i did it and it works great

Comment: @Silentcow glad you solved it!!

Answer (score -2):

If you want the center of the bounding box:
Just do:

```
image = cv2.imread('res-orig.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cnts = cv2.findContours(gray_image, cv2.RETR_LIST , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
x, y, w, h= cv2.boundingRect(cnts[0][0])
cx, cy = x + w//2, y + h//2

img = cv2.circle(gray_image, (cx, cy), 4, (255, 255, 255), -1)
img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (205, 205, 205), 1,)
```

The center of mass is not always the center of bounding box so if you want the center of bounding box just use `cv2.boundingRect()`.

Seems like the flag you were using for `cv2.findContours` was not returning any contour.

`cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`
Changed to:
`cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE`

`cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL`
Changed to:
`cv2.RETR_LIST`

Also removed `threshold` and `blur`.

[image: result]

Check the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71ab10df56aed56c89a026580adc9431f58).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/17kOp.png

Comment: Thanks, but It gives nothing. The result is the same

Comment: Did you checked your code? Can I see the image result? Because I tried your changes, but  still get nothing. Also can you add lines of code for drawing contours and circle on image?

Comment: Can you add the full code to get acquainted please?

Comment: I tried and finally got a circle on the center, but I also need a drawn rectangle around it. How can I draw it?

Comment: you missed the point of white contours on black bg

Comment: Sorry @berak if you are not pleased with my answer.

Comment: @berak if you have your own point of how to solve this question, feel free to share